# didBegin function doesn't work well on IOS 11.3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I developed a game using swift, it worked very well before I updated my system to IOS 11.3 for iPhone. In my game, when the bullet contact with the enemy, the two SKSpriteNode will be removed immediately, and the variable "gameScore" will be added by 1 as expected. But now, every time the bullet contact with enemy, the "gameScore" will be added by the number much larger than 1 ( depending on the speed of SKSpriteNode".

Therefore, I guess the didBegin function is still been called after the SKSpriteNode is removed. It seems that there is a time delay in the didBegin fucntion. Does everyone meet the same problem?

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var body1 = SKPhysicsBody()
    var body2 = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }

    if body1.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Player && body2.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Bullet {

        gameScore += 1
        gameLabel1.text = "SCORE: \(gameScore)"
        body1.node?.removeFromParent()
        body2.node?.removeFromParent()

    }
}
```

Comment: this issue has been addressed many times,  I have serious doubts on it working prior to 11.3, I think you just weren't noticing the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find my answer explaining this thoroughly, I think it was in the documents, so if anybody finds the duplicate, feel free to mark it as such.

First, let's try and understand how contacts work.

During the physics phase, a pool is created for your node that lists all of the contact points it touches.  This pool will retain all of your nodes.

E.G.

```
let pool : [SKPhysicsContact] = [{node1.side1,node2.side1},{node1.side1,node2.side2}]
```

We then iterate through all the contact points and call the `didBegin` function.

```
for contact in pool
{
   scene.didBegin(contact)
}
```

Now we enter the code that you have provided:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var body1 = SKPhysicsBody()
    var body2 = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }

    if body1.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Player && body2.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Bullet {

        gameScore += 1
        gameLabel1.text = "SCORE: \(gameScore)"
        body1.node?.removeFromParent()
        body2.node?.removeFromParent()

    }
}
```

If I were to inline your code into the for loop, it would end up looking like this:

```
for contact in pool
{

    var body1 = SKPhysicsBody()
    var body2 = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }

    if body1.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Player && body2.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Bullet {

        gameScore += 1
        gameLabel1.text = "SCORE: \(gameScore)"
        body1.node?.removeFromParent()
        body2.node?.removeFromParent()

    }
}
```

Now as you can see, calling `body1.node?.removeFromParent()` is not going to do anything to stop the for loop from happening twice.  All this is going to do is set `parent` to nil, but the contact and the node both still exist, making the next loop successful.

So what we need to do is some how prevent the loop from processing again.

Now there are several ways to do this:

1) Check if parent is nil:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    guard let _ = contact.bodyA.node.parent else {return}
```

This works, but what if somewhere along the way bodyA.node becomes nil, our code will crash.

2) Check if node or parent is nil:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    guard let _ = contact.bodyA.node?.parent else {return}
```

Now we know our code is safe.  Oh no,  we had 2 different nodes collide at the same time, and the node was removed from the scene, how do I process both, I just removed the node?

3)  Move the node to a temporary location, check if node is in the removal node, and clean up at the end up update:

```
let removalNode = SKNode()
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var body1 : SKPhysicsBody!
    var body2 : SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }


    if body1.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Player && 
       body2.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Bullet && 
       body1.node?.parent != removalNode{

           gameScore += 1
           gameLabel1.text = "SCORE: \(gameScore)"
           removalNode.addChild(body1)
           removalNode.addChild(body2)
    }  
}

func didFinishUpdate(){
    removalNode.removeAllChildren()
}
```

Now let's see we placed a token in the game, and our game rule is if player hits token and bullet at the same time, the player score still goes up by 10.  With the current setup, we can now do that:

```
let removalNode = SKNode()
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var body1 : SKPhysicsBody!
    var body2 : SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }


    if body1.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Player && 
       body2.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Bullet && 
       body1.node?.parent != removalNode{

           gameScore += 1
           gameLabel1.text = "SCORE: \(gameScore)"
           removalNode.addChild(body1)
           removalNode.addChild(body2)
    }  
    if body1.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Player && 
       body2.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Token &&
       body2.node?.parent != removalNode{

           gameScore += 10
           gameLabel1.text = "SCORE: \(gameScore)"
           removalNode.addChild(body2)
    }  

}

func didFinishUpdate(){
    removalNode.removeAllChildren()
}
```

Now let's walk through the example where we hit bullet first, then token.

contact->player hit bullet
did begin:
player is alive
player hit bullet = true
game score increased
player is dead
bullet is dead
player hit token = false
end begin
contact->player hit token
did begin:
player is dead
player hit bullet = false
player hit token = true
gamescore is increased by 10
end begin

The game is now over, and the gamescore increased 11, which is the rules our game has in place.

But what if the game rule is if a player hits a bullet and token is hit at the same time, then the score is not added?  You may think "let's just check if player is in the `removalNode` to not add the score.  Well you would be wrong then, because what if the pipeline happens to be token then bullet.

contact->player hit token
did begin:
player is alive
player hit bullet = false
player hit token = true
gamescore is increased by 10
end begin
contact->player hit bullet
did begin:
player is alive
player hit bullet = true
game score increased
player is dead
bullet is dead
player hit token = false
end begin

score is now 11, when it should be 1, violating our game rule.

How do we fix this?

Well we move scoring to the `didFinishUpdate` method instead, and we use `userData` to mark tokens:

```
let removalNode = SKNode()
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var body1 : SKPhysicsBody!
    var body2 : SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }


    if body1.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Player && 
       body2.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Bullet && 
       body1.node?.parent != removalNode{

           removalNode.addChild(body1)
           removalNode.addChild(body2)
    }  
    if body1.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Player && 
       body2.categoryBitMask == physicscategories.Token &&
       body2.node.parent != removalNode
       //Make sure userData is allocated
       if body1.userData = nil {body1.userData = [String:NSObject]()}
       // If body.userData[tokenScore] is nil, default to 0 then add 10
       body1.userData[tokenScore] = (body1.userData[tokenScore] ?? 0) + 10
       removalNode.addChild(body2)
    }  

}

func didFinishUpdate(){
    if player.parent = removalNode
    {
      gameScore += 1
    }
    else
    {
      //if userdata exists and token score has a value, then add it, otherwise add 0
      gameScore += player.usedData?["tokenScore"] ?? 0
    }
    gameLabel1.text = "SCORE: \(gameScore)"

    removalNode.removeAllChildren()
}
```

Now our gamerule states that the token only gets added when the player is not in the removalNode.

Alternatively, if you want to not use `userData`, you could always check how many tokens are in the "removalNode" children, and add the score accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, boss. The problem is solved and your explanation is very clear!

Comment: nice answer and very thorough